# Combine lists of dictionaries with different values

Tags: python

I have list of dictionaries with matching keys like this.

```
[{'account_general_permission': {'view': False, 'create': False, 'edit': False, 'delete': False}}, 
{'control_section_permission': {'view': False, 'create': False, 'edit': False, 'delete': False}}, 
{'account_general_permission': {'view': True, 'create': True, 'edit': True, 'delete': False}}, 
{'control_section_permission': {'view': False, 'create': False, 'edit': False, 'delete': False}}]
```

I need to combine all matching keys together with the value inside the `dicts` where if there is true for some `key` its given priority over false.

So result should look something like

```
{'account_general_permission': {'view': True, 'create': True, 'edit': True, 'delete': False}}, 
{'control_section_permission': {'view': False, 'create': False, 'edit': False, 'delete': False}}]
```

What would the fastest way to achieve this as speed is crucial to perform this.

My attempt
*Assuming list is sort based on keys and I have a variable x to know how many times a key repeats in a list*

```
new_list = np.array_split(new_list, len(permission))

for i in new_list:
    for j in i:
        for k, l in j.items():
            for m, n in l.items():
                if n == True:
                    l[m] = n
```

This partially works, also doesn't look the cleanest.

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Comment: As for speed, is the dataset large? Is the dataset used for other things or could this dataset be built in a different way to make the question easier?

Comment: @Bahrom updated question with what I've attempted so far.

Comment: @tdelaney it is not a large dataset. Let's just assume length of dictionaries would mostly be this.

Comment: I'm not sure what numpy is doing here. Isn't this just a list of dictionaries? numpy would slow this one down.

Comment: @tdelaney knowing how many times the dictionary will repeat I was taking splitting the list into parts to have all keys together than compare and change values of all dictionaries  inside. Numpy is just used to split the dictionary into chunks where every dictionary has same key.

Comment: @coder - Your example doesn't seem to have anything to do with the data. What are new_list and permission? It seems like an unnecessary complication. One reason why I asked about size was whether building an array or a pandas dataframe was worth the expense. Another is that this looks like something that could be done in a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
data = [{'account_general_permission': {'view': False, 'create': False, 'edit': False, 'delete': False}}, 
        {'control_section_permission': {'view': False, 'create': False, 'edit': False, 'delete': False}}, 
        {'account_general_permission': {'view': True, 'create': True, 'edit': True, 'delete': False}}, 
        {'control_section_permission': {'view': False, 'create': False, 'edit': False, 'delete': False}}]

# Let's make a new dictionary~
new_data = {}
for x in data:
    # Each "dictionary" in your list appears to just be a single key/value pair.
    key, values = tuple(x.items())[0]
    # If we've added this key to the dictionary already...
    if key in new_data:
        for k in values:
            # If that inner key isn't already True, or doesn't exist.
            if not new_data[key].get(k):
                # Overwrite this inner key's value OR add the new key:value pair.
                new_data[key][k] |= values[k]
    # Otherwise we can just add this dict to the new dict.
    else:
        new_data |= x

print(new_data)

# Output:

{'account_general_permission': {'view': True, 'create': True, 'edit': True, 'delete': False}, 
 'control_section_permission': {'view': False, 'create': False, 'edit': False, 'delete': False}}
```

---

An overkill, but one-line approached using `pandas` could look like:

```
data = (pd.concat([pd.DataFrame.from_dict(x, 'index') for x in data])
          .groupby(level=0)
          .max()
          .to_dict('index'))

print(data)

# Output

{'account_general_permission': {'view': True, 'create': True, 'edit': True, 'delete': False}, 
 'control_section_permission': {'view': False, 'create': False, 'edit': False, 'delete': False}}
```

Answer (score 1):

this should work

```py
from collections import Counter

data = [{'account_general_permission': {'view': False, 'create': False, 'edit': False, 'delete': False}}, 
{'control_section_permission': {'view': False, 'create': False, 'edit': False, 'delete': False}}, 
{'account_general_permission': {'view': True, 'create': True, 'edit': True, 'delete': False}}, 
{'control_section_permission': {'view': False, 'create': False, 'edit': False, 'delete': False}}]

counters = {list(dicto.keys())[0]: Counter() for dicto in data} 

for element in data:
    for key, data in element.items():
        counters[key].update(data)


result = [{key: {item: bool(val) for item, val in data.items()}} for key, data in counters.items()]
result
```

output:

```
{'account_general_permission': {'view': True, 'create': True, 'edit': True, 'delete': False}}, 
{'control_section_permission': {'view': False, 'create': False, 'edit': False, 'delete': False}}
```

Comment: @BeRT2me I agree. thanks for the tip always good to learn

Comment: I think your approach is interesting, but it's not going to be useful unless you adapt it to allow for arbitrary keys... aka you can't hard code `counters` like that~

Answer (score 0):

```
lod = [{'account_general_permission': {'view': False, 'create': False, 'edit':
                                       False, 'delete': False}},
       {'control_section_permission': {'view': False, 'create': False, 'edit':
                                       False, 'delete': False}},
       {'account_general_permission': {'view': True, 'create': True, 'edit':
                                       True, 'delete': False}},
       {'control_section_permission': {'view': False, 'create': False, 'edit':
                                       False, 'delete': False}}]

result = {}
for d in lod:
    perm_name, perms = next(iter(d.items()))
    result[perm_name] = {perm_elem: any([perm_val,
                                         result.get(perm_name, {}
                                                    ).get(perm_elem, False)])
                         for perm_elem, perm_val in perms.items()}
```

```
{'account_general_permission': {'create': True,
                                'delete': False,
                                'edit': True,
                                'view': True},
 'control_section_permission': {'create': False,
                                'delete': False,
                                'edit': False,
                                'view': False}}
```

The result is a dict of dicts, though, but I feel like it's a more natural data structure for this task.

Comment: This assumes that all of the inner keys will always be present. If any are missing, you have the potential to lose them.

Comment: @BeRT2me, good point, I thought I took that into account, but still assumed all inner keys present.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the numpy stuff, but your example applied to the original list is already reasonable, especially considering that this is a small data set. Iteration is faster than indexing and a dictionary's update function that is written in C is a bit faster still. So, using a `defaultdict` to create items as needed, you could do

```
import collections

data = [{'account_general_permission': {'view': False, 'create': False, 'edit': False, 'delete': False}}, 
{'control_section_permission': {'view': False, 'create': False, 'edit': False, 'delete': False}},
{'account_general_permission': {'view': True, 'create': True, 'edit': True, 'delete': False}},
{'control_section_permission': {'view': False, 'create': False, 'edit': False, 'delete': False}}]

resolved = collections.defaultdict(lambda: {'view': False, 'create': False,
    'edit': False, 'delete': False})

for perms in data:
    for perm_name, perm_vals in perms.items():
        resolved[perm_name].update((n,v) for n,v in perm_vals.items() if v)

for k,v in resolved.items():
    print(f"{k}: {v}")
```

This solution does not update the dictionaries in the original table.

Comment: How about collecting all the keys for `resolved` from `data`, instead of hardcoding them by hand? =)

Comment: @Klas - That would alter the original dicts in data, which means that it couldn't be used for other purposes. And you'd have to go back to using explicit `for`s. Another option is to initialize with an empty dict, and only set things when True, Then, when using the result, use a `get` with a default value of False.

Comment: Why would original data be altered?  Just iterate through it and collect the keys in a set: https://dpaste.org/Yrhi5

Comment: @KlasŠ. - I thought you were suggesting using the first dict of each type as the base. Then you'd have the problem. In your example you go through the extra expense of gathering the keys and then have a more expensive way of building the new dict via iteration. It seems like these are well-known keys, so my way should be faster.

Comment: Well, sure, hardcoding is less robust but faster, obviously.

Comment: @KlasŠ. - Its robust. These are well-known permission keys. In a situation like this, its better to have hard coded keys.

Answer (score 0):

Let's get crazy and functional:

```
lod = [{'account_general_permission': {'view': False, 'create': False, 'edit':
                                       False, 'delete': False}},
       {'control_section_permission': {'view': False, 'create': False, 'edit':
                                       False, 'delete': False}},
       {'account_general_permission': {'view': True, 'create': True, 'edit':
                                       True, 'delete': False}},
       {'control_section_permission': {'view': False, 'create': False, 'edit':
                                       False, 'delete': False}}]

from functools import reduce
from itertools import groupby


def get_key(d):
    return next(iter(d.keys()))


def get_val(d):
    return next(iter(d.values()))


def merge_dicts(d, perm_d):
    unwrappe_d = get_val(perm_d)
    keys = set(d) | set(unwrappe_d)
    return {p: any(d.get(p) for d in (d, unwrappe_d))
            for p in keys}



grouped = groupby(sorted(lod, key=get_key), get_key)

result = [{p: reduce(merge_dicts, perm_dicts, {})}
          for p, perm_dicts in grouped]
```